# alter value in isnull

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, where-clause, isnull

I have a stored procedure where I'm serching for part of a column if a parameter isn't null.

The problem is that the value I'm searching for is mixed up in a long string of other values. Here's an example of what a row might look like:

```
'...value=153139,example=xyz,param=15,morestuff=otherthings...' //ignore the actual names, it's just examples for SO
```

So this wont work because it would potentially select the wrong thing (`value=153139`would cause a match if `@param = '15'`):

```
WHERE
    [column] LIKE ISNULL(@param, [column])
```

This wouldn't work either:

```
WHERE
    [column] LIKE '%param=' + ISNULL(@param, [column]) + '%'
```

The perfect thing for me would be something like  `ISNULL(check_expression, replacement_if_null, replecement_if_not_null)`, but to my knowledge, that doesn't exist..

P.S. I know that the way the information is stored isn't optimal, but it's what the system uses and I have to work with it =/ So no comments like "You should split the column up so that it only contains one value" please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try a case statement:

```
case when check_expression is null then replacement_if_null else replecement_if_not_null end
```

or

```
 [column] LIKE '%param=' + ISNULL(@param, [column]) + ',%' -- comma added before the last %
```

Cast @param if it is necessary and make sure you don't have hidden space around the values (rtrim or ltrim can be used to remove them)

Comment: The case statement looks good, I'll try it. The other one wouldn't work because if @param is null it would try to match `[column]` with `'%param='+[column]+'%'`

Comment: I went for your first suggestion and it works fine =) Thanks alot!